# Load chrome extension url in another chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension which overrides new tab. But I want to make new tab overriding **optional**. This is not possible in a proper non-hackish way, as override rule is entered in the manifest and is not possible to change it at runtime.

To solve this I have decided to make a separate extension. This separate extension will override the new tab (not the main extension) and will open the main extension webpage in the new tab (`chrome-extension://hclbghnhiklgejahckgmpldjgfgleofc/index.html`)

I can use JS to open the above link, but in that case, the URL is visible in the address bar. I am trying to open the above line in the iframe. But it seems my secondary chrome extension is blocking the main extension url. I have added the URL in `content_security_policy` also.

```
<body>
    <iframe src="chrome-extension://hclbghnhiklgejahckgmpldjgfgleofc/index.html"></iframe>
</body>
```

Comment: What do you mean by __overriding tab__?

Comment: @MadeOfAir My chrome extension replaces the default NewTab

Comment: I don't know how using 2 extensions to override a new tab is not hackish. Also if this extension goes live someday, how do you ask a user to install 2 extensions?

Comment: How about this https://dev.to/chinchang/overriding-new-tab-page-in-chrome-extension-conditionally ?

Comment: If CSP were relevant, you should have seen errors in devtools console.

Comment: I think the embedded page should be listed in web_accessible_resources section of that extension's manifest.

Comment: @MadeOfAir You are very right... Only way a user will install the secondary extension is from primary extension :)